# MongoS refusing connections during network split

Tags: cluster, mongodb, sharding

I am exploring sharded MongoDB clusters, and I have trouble understanding MongoS's behavior during a network split.

My test environment works as expected until I simulate a network split.
In the "smallest" network partition, I have:

- N MongoS servers
- only 1 config server (out of 3 total), in SECONDARY status
- and N shard servers

In this partition:

- at first, all MongoDB servers + MongoS still accept connections and behave as expected
- if I restart these MongoDB+MongoS servers => MongoS servers start but refuse connections (MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED).

Do you know why? I must be missing something obvious.
As far as I can tell from startup logs, MongoS sends queries like `{"find":"shards", "readConcern":{"level":"majority"}}` to the config server, which seems guaranteed to fail during a network split (`Command timed out waiting for read concern to be satisfied`).

Thanks for any help

Comment: Repro without shard servers: create a 3-server configuration replica set, only start one (to simulate a network split), and start MongoS based on that configuration replica set. MongoS starts but does not accept connections (ECONNREFUSED).